# SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, ldapconnection

I have a problem about a connection to an LDPS server with C# code.
 
I'm working on Windows server 2003 SP2 and i try to connect to an LDAP server with a c# code.
 
The framework is .net 2.0
 
Ther error that the .net show me is:

Code:81   Cannot connect to ldap server

The code that i use is this :

```
LdapConnection con = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(szLdapId));
con.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
con.Credential = new NetworkCredential(szUserName, szPassword);
con.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
con.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ServerCallback); // the server callback function return a true value
con.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
con.Bind();
```

the variable szLdapId is "servername:636"
 
The bind connection throw me an exception: "The LDAP server is unavailable."
 
I try to connect to ldap server with Apache DirectoryStudio and o can connect without problem.
 
The only thing that i see is that the variable

```
 con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer
```

is set to false also after i set it to true, i try to force it to true but it don't change
I try to make some test it windows server 2008 and it works.

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Unable to turn on SecureSocketLayer with DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278020/unable-to-turn-on-securesocketlayer-with-directoryservices-protocols-ldapconnect)

It says that SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer may not be the problem.

Comment: Ok but where is the problem? :D
I modify the start post adding that:
in win 2008 all works fine 
and the error when i make the bind is:
Cannot connect to ldap server (error code 81)